# Node.js - mysql: Bad field Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, async.js

I parse a big csv and insert row per row into my mysql tables.

After parsing I do a lot of calculation and transforming and save it to a new Object

```
  obj.push({                                                         
   "ID": value.id,
   "col1": value.calc1,
   ... });
```

After the Object is complete I do:

```
async.forEach(obj, function (Insertobj, callback) {

 var query = conn.query('INSERT INTO table SET ?', Insertobj);

  },function (err){ 
      if (err) {                                                     
        console.log(err);                                             
        console.log('failed to process');
 }}
```

After running through the obj I get =>

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'..
```

But he inserts the complete Object into my table! I don't have any column called NaN or empty cols. How can I debug it? I try to set the console.log to err.sql, but he print "undefined". Using debug:true in connection didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how escaping mysql values works using the node js module. The error is due to you not specifying what column you want to update. In addition to this, the escaped values should be filled in using an array instead of an object. With values being in the order they are escaped in the query. Your code could look as follows:

```
    valuesarray.push([                                                         
       value.id,
       value.calc1
    ]);

    async.forEach(valuesarray, function ( insertarray, callback ) {

        var query = conn.query('INSERT INTO table SET ID = ?, col1 = 
        ?', insertarray);

    },function (err){ 
        if (err) {                                                     
            console.log(err);                                             
            console.log('failed to process');
        }
    });
```